# how to get type registry for substrate v4.0.0 parachain?

Tags: parachain, substrate-node-template, relay-chain, types

so i have a parachain upgraded to substrate 4.0.0
and i need the type registry of this chain in order to work with [subscan-essentials](https://github.com/subscan-explorer/subscan-essentials)

normally with substrate-node-template subscan-essentials work smoothly
but not sure about substrate 4.0.0 parachain.

Comment: I've the same issue